# The makefile creates the object files in the src directory rather than objects folder

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Thanks!, I have updated my makefile now. And the .o are created in the src directory.
here is the makefile and output. The makefile throws the error because all the .o are created in the src folders. I don't know why? I am new to Makefile so kindly please bear with my silly questions.

```
# This is the Vpath; as my source directory is in the src folder - all the .c files
#folder structure
#Gif_Utility
#-->src/*.c
#-->include/*.h
VPATH = src:include:objects
CFLAGS = -I ./include -g -Wall -DDEBUG

OBJS =./objects
# Look at the CFLAGS here; it has -DDEBUG because in my code, I have #ifdef DEBUG
# Look at the CFLAGS here; -Wall : To generate all the compiler warnings.
# include is required as my compilation depends on the .h files.

# The LD flags to link the shared objects 
#LDFLAGS= 
#in my mini-project, I am using maths library, Thus, I have lm.
# lc to link my main function with crt1.o

#what is the compiler, am I using.
#This is a good practice since I can modify these flags when cross-compiling.
cc= gcc

#PATH for the LIBS 
#This might be useful while cross-compiling.
LIBS= -lm -lc

target: $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ./src/*.c))
    @echo "making target"
    @mkdir -p ./objects
    $(cc) $(patsubst ./src/%.c,./objects/%.o,$(wildcard ./src/*.c)) $(LIBS) -o gif 


./objects/%.o: ./src/%.c
    @echo "making objects now"
    $(cc) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 


#It is always better to write a PHONY rule for a rules like clean.
#It may happen that in source sandbox, you have a clean file. This may invoke the clean file.
#In order to prevent invoking a clean file during make clean; We give this general rule as PHONY
#PHONY tells the MAKEFILE that there is a rule clean, not a file called clean.
#Generally use PHONY for all, install, clean, distclean, 
.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    @echo "cleaning everything"
    @rm -f *.o
    @rm -f gif  
    @echo "clearning .o from src"
    @rm -f ./src/*.o
    @rm -f ./objects/*.o


$make target

cc -I ./include -g -Wall -DDEBUG   -c -o src/sysm.o src/sysm.c
cc -I ./include -g -Wall -DDEBUG   -c -o src/x86_main.o src/x86_main.c
src/x86_main.c:11:9: warning: second argument of ‘main’ should be ‘char **’ [-Wmain]
src/x86_main.c: In function ‘main’:
src/x86_main.c:16:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘display_init’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
src/x86_main.c:19:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Gif_Read’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
making target
gcc ./objects/gif_display.o ./objects/gif_lzw.o ./objects/gif_read.o ./objects/sysm.o ./objects/x86_main.o -lm -lc -o gif 
gcc: error: ./objects/gif_display.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: ./objects/gif_lzw.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: ./objects/gif_read.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: ./objects/sysm.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: ./objects/x86_main.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [target] Error
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix your patsubst to change the directory part of the filenames as well as the suffixes:

```
$(patsubst ./src/%.c,./objects/%.o,$(wildcard ./src/*.c))
```

You have other issues in your makefile too, e.g. this target has the wrong prerequisite:

```
./objects/%.o: %.c
```

The source file should be something like `./src/%.c`

And the rule for that target is wrong, it outputs to `./objects/$@` which would expand to something like `./objects/./objects/x86_main.o`

Comment: `/objects/`, not `/objs/`

Comment: There is one problem here. cc -I ./include -g -Wall -DDEBUG   -c -o src/x86_main.o src/x86_main.c. Basically, it is creating a objects in the src folder.

Comment: That command doesn't match any of your makefile rules, why is the `.c` file coming after the `.o` file when your makefile rules put it before?  I've updated by answer to point out some other errors.